# CakePHP Write URL path from initial search() action pagination array

Tags: arrays, url, cakephp, url-rewriting

I've hit a roadblock and cannot for the life of me get over.

I have a search() action which is working as expected.

From that function, I pass my pagination value to the results page and I get an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [controller] => plans
    [action] => search
    [0] => 35
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 97389
)
```

ALL search results display correct (and array data is correct). BUT my url ONLY displays the Model and Action value when the initial results are displayed like so:

```
...plans/search
```

And if I do a **paginator()** **sort()** (in my header fields) or Next >> my pagination array prints to the url like so:

```
 ...plans/search/45/0/0/0/97389/page:1/sort:monthly_cost/direction:desc
```

Everything is working as expected BUT I need my initial search to display the url path as it does when **paginator()** or **sort()** is used.

I've tried imploding the array and tacking it onto the url (no dice).
I've tried to rewrite the url with the array (but this conflicts with the pagination)..
I've tried a bucket load of get and post ideas.. (no dice)..

Am I overlooking something VERY simple here? Someone please send any ideas you might have. This is kicking my butt!

Comment: What redirects to the results page after the search is performed?

Comment: @Amy. I am not sure I understand your question re the redirect. Can you clarify please : )

Comment: you said "From that function, I pass my pagination value to the results page and I get an array like so:"  So, my question is, how are you passing the results to the results page and navigating there?

Comment: I have a rather large query, but the main elements are passed from the controller like so: $this->set('searchdetails', array_merge($url, $searchdetails)); searchdetails contains the array as I posted above.

Comment: I believe, then, that your problem is that you should format the link to the search action to have default values for the sort and search variables, and then call your search function as such.

Comment: @Amy. I was thinking a similar thing, but if the default values are set then the users first search would not be correct, right? I am trying to wrap my head around this, and if I could just write the search array data to the url in the initial search, it would solve my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this:

In my search function, this is what I did:

```
if($this->RequestHandler->isPost()) {
    $this->Session->write('search_form_sess', $this->data); 
          $initial_url = $ApplicantAge . '/' . $SpouseAge . '/' . $NumberChildren . '/' .  $Vision . '/' . $Zip;
       $this->redirect(array('action' => 'search', $initial_url));
    exit();
 }
```

As you can see I am also capturing the search form session data to pass to the search form to hold the search values in the inputs.